# How do I create a single exe file to distribute a C# application?

Tags: c#, exe, windows-installer, addin-express

I have finished a c# Add-In application for outlook. And I want to create a single exe file for distribution. I have been on Add-in Express but I am not looking for a ClickOnce, ClickTwice or web based solution. At the moment i have a created a setup.exe but that file depends on an .msi file in order to run. Can someone teach me how to create a single exe file? Thank you very much.

Comment: Are you sure msi file is not everything you need? In many occasions setup.exe can be ignored.

Comment: @Alex the MSI file works just fine, however i would like to have an extension of EXE as we are all accustomed of installing and running exe files.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am going to check that post out right now and we will let you know if it helped or not.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Yes thank you I saw those instructions and are following them, everything seems to be going smoothly. I will update you on how it goes!

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer and deleted my old comments, you can delete your comments too if you like.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to package the setup.exe and .msi file in to a single distributable .exe file a common easy solution is create a Self Extracting Zip Archive that unzips the .msi and the setup.exe to a temporary directory then runs the setup.exe. See [this SuperUser.com post](https://superuser.com/questions/42788/is-it-possible-to-execute-a-file-after-extraction-from-a-7-zip-self-extracting-a) for instructions to do it totally free using only [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/)<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sup>1: The "SFX modules" are not part of the normal download and instead are found in the [LZMA SDK download](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).</sup>